# Can Azure App Service be used to host different client apps / websites?

Tags: azure

I'm currently thinking of doing some stuff with azure and was wondering if it is possible to host different web apps or websites in a single app service? I would like to handle the hosting for my clients but don't want to charge a lot of money for the service and based on some of the app service prices for production I have seen I don't think it is fair to be charging those prices to some of my customers.

I also need the apps/websites to have their own domain names pointing to them respectively.

I have done some research and see that some people are using azure active directory to setup a multi tenant system, is this the approach I need to be taking? Also take into consideration that most of my apps/websites have their own identity setup for backend management and need the apps to be somewhat independent.

Would I take the same approach to the SQL database's as well?

If someone could shed some light on this subject I would greatly appreciate it. I just need some guidance and not a full tutorial as I can learn to do it myself.

Comment: It might be possible but it becomes a complex solution that you need to maintain. Also keep in mind for lots of clients you may need to have multiple instances to satisfy the load. With regards to multiple identities in one Azure App, we could not find enough documentation that gave us enough info to use user assigned identities.

Answer (score 0):

You can host multiple web apps or websites within a single Azure App Service. This is known as "multi-tenant" hosting. Azure App Service supports this by allowing you to deploy multiple applications to the same underlying infrastructure, each with its own configuration and domain.

To reduce costs, you can place multiple apps/websites within the same App Service plan. This will share the same resources (like CPU and memory) across your apps.

Each app can have its own custom domain name. You can configure custom domains for each app by adding DNS records (like CNAME or A records) pointing to your App Service's default domain or using Azure's App Service Managed Certificates to enable HTTPS for custom domains.

While apps within the same App Service plan share resources, they are isolated at the process level. This means that they can run different codebases with different identities, configurations, and dependencies.

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), is a good approach for handling authentication and authorization across multiple applications, especially if they need to be independent. Azure AD's multi-tenant capabilities allow you to support users from different organizations or tenants while keeping the apps isolated.

While this approach can help reduce costs, there are some trade-offs. Apps within the same App Service plan will share resources, which could affect performance if one app experiences high traffic. Also, consider security and isolation concerns when deploying multiple apps together.

For Databasrs you can create a separate SQL database for each app.